# PHP routing works in localhosted app but not when webhosted

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, heroku

I'm trying to build an API with PHP, I have the logic files stored in different folders, I followed some tutorial to make a PHP router and it works locally for example:

```
localhost:4000/products
```

But when I use the same URL when the app is hosted on heroku it doesn't work.

```
https://hostedapp.herokuapp.com/products
```

and gives this error:

```
Warning: include(view/products.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/index.php on line 12

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/products.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /app/index.php on line 12
```

I've been trying for the past few days to change the way the paths are written and checked all StackOverflow questions related to it but nothing seems to work.

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once('router.php');

route('/',function(){
  echo "Index page";
});

route('/products',function(){
    include('view/products.php');
});

route('/product-delete',function(){
    include('view/product-delete.php');
});

route('/product-add',function(){
    include 'view/product-add.php';
});


$endpoint = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
dispatch($endpoint);
?>
```

This is router.php

```
<?php

$routes = [];

function route($endpoint, $callback){
    global $routes;
    $endpoint = trim($endpoint, '/');
    $routes[$endpoint]=$callback;
}

function dispatch($endpoint){
    global $routes;
    $endpoint = trim($endpoint,'/');
    $callback=$routes[$endpoint];
    return call_user_func($callback);
}
?>
```

and this is.htaccess (Copied it from a StackOverflow answer)

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 
 #RewriteEngine on
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**EDIT**: I tried `include(__DIR__) . '../subfolder/file.php'` and `include(__DIR__ . '../subfolder/file.php')` and it gives the same error.

I also tried the that shows when I echo **DIR** or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on heroku which is just /app/ and it still gives the same error. `/app/subfolder/file.php`.

Comment: Silly question but did you just forget to upload that particular file?

Comment: @ADyson I have git initialized in the root API folder and all of the files and subfolders in it are committed and pushed to Heroku

Comment: _"I have git initialized in the root API folder"_ - What "API" folder? Are you saying that the above code is located in a sub folder and not in the root folder?

Comment: @M.Eriksson The project consists of a react frontend folder and PHP API backend which is the root directory for the PHP project, so by API folder I mean the root directory.

Comment: The working directory is NOT what you _think_ it is... use absolute pathes instead

Comment: @HonkderHase I tried using absolute path and got this error ***Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\deploy\api\router.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/index.php on line 5***

Comment: Then this path is wrong. Use the constant `__DIR__` and resolve it from the directory in which the including file is in. How did you compose the absolute path?

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\deploy\api\router.php`....looks like the path in your local environment. That is highly unlikely to be the path in the deployed environment (I'd guess Heroku doesn't run on Windows, for a start...). Instead use the DIR constant as suggested above, so PHP can create the first part of the path for you automatically based on its configuration.

Comment: @HonkderHase I got the absolute path from the localhost server (My bad) but I tried getting the __DIR__ on the hosted project and all it shows is /app/ which I also tried and it gives the same error **I'll made an edit for better readability**

Comment: `include(__DIR__ . '../subfolder/file.php')` you should examine _closely_ what `__DIR__` contains!